# Supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key with Google APIs

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, php-openssl

I'm trying to test this example that I found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-api-php-client/jaRYDWdpteQ/xbNTLfDhUggJ) so that I can do a direct upload on the client side without having the user login using Google Cloud Storage.

All of the constants expressed have their correct values, and the path is correct and does not have an empty contents.

The error I'm getting:

```
openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key
```

My function implemented is:

```
public static function storageURL( $id, $method = 'GET', $duration = 10 ) {
    $key = file_get_contents(self::KEY_FILE);
    $pkey = openssl_get_privatekey($key, 'notasecret');
    $expires = time( ) + $duration;
    $content_type = ($method == 'PUT') ? 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' : ''; 
    $to_sign = ($method . "\n" . 
    /* Content-MD5 */ "\n" . 
    $content_type . "\n" . 
    $expires . "\n" . 
    '/'.self::BUCKET_NAME.'/' . $id); 
    $signature = '*Signature will go here*';
    if (!openssl_sign( $to_sign, $signature, $pkey, 'sha256' ))
    { 
        error_log( 'openssl_sign failed!' );
        $signature = '<failed>'; 
    } else { 
        $signature = urlencode( base64_encode( $signature ) ); 
    } 
    return ('https://'.self::BUCKET_NAME.'.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/' .
        $id .
        '?GoogleAccessId=' . self::SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME .
        '&Expires=' . $expires . '&Signature=' . $signature);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to use `openssl_pkcs12_read` to read the key file, not `file_get_contents`. Second, I believe you want to leave off the second parameter to `openssl_get_privatekey`.

I highly recommend you use [google-api-php-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) for this, which has [Google_P12Signer.php](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/auth/Google_P12Signer.php)

Comment: So I can generate the URL's using just this?

Comment: What is "this"? If you mean the google-api-php-client, then yes

Comment: Oh... where are you finding the documentation to the api-library?

Answer (score 0):

The safer way is to use `Google_Signer_P12` class shipped with [Google API PHP client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) to do that.

Code sample:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'PATH/TO/API/src');
require_once 'Google/Signer/P12.php';

$p12contents = file_get_contents('FILE.p12');
$googleSigner = new Google_Signer_P12($p12contents, 'notasecret');
$signature = $googleSigner->sign($data);
```

Comment: google_signer_p12 was removed in the new version, what to use instead?