# File names with spaces returning signature mismatch error for Signed URLs in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Google Cloud Storages Signed URLs feature with the below code. File names without spaces work fine, but those with spaces give this error:

`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.`

I'm passing the file name via ajax to the below code, which then returns the link to the user. I've tried a combination of rawurlencode, urlencode & urldecode but can't seem to work it out.

Thanks in advance

```
$bucket = 'savoy_storage';
if (isset($_GET['file']))
{
    $file = urldecode($_GET['file']);
    $link = storageURL( $bucket, $file);
    echo $link;
}

//https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-php-client/kvN-yoyzf_w

function storageURL( $bucketName, $file) { 
    $expiry = time() + 3600;    
    $accessId = '1234@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
    $stringPolicy = "GET\n\n\n".$expiry."\n/".$bucketName."/".$file;
    $fp = fopen('key.pem', 'r');
    $priv_key = fread($fp, 8192);
    fclose($fp);
    $pkeyid = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key,"password"); 
    if (openssl_sign( $stringPolicy, $signature, $pkeyid, 'sha256' )) {
        $signature = urlencode( base64_encode( $signature ) );    
        return 'https://'.$bucketName.'.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/'.$file.'?
         GoogleAccessId='.$accessId.'&Expires='.$expiry.'&Signature='.$signature;
    }

}
```

If it helps here is the returned XML from the link:

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.
</Message>
<StringToSign>
GET 1391312980 /savoy_storage/August%20promotions.xlsx
</StringToSign>
</Error>
```

Comment: You may find this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149200/openssl-sign-supplied-key-param-cannot-be-coerced-into-a-private-key-using-go

I also recommend you use [google-api-php-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) or openssl_pkcs12_read().