# using google-api-php-client not able to create proper signedurl

Tags: php, authentication, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

bucketIn my project, I am uploading user's files to cloud storage, so when user wants to download that file I want to generate signedurl from google cloud, to limit access to the files to that specific user only, So I have tried following php code to do that

`

```
function storageURL( $id, $method = 'GET', $duration = 10 ) { 
        $expires = time( ) + $duration*60; 
        $content_type = ($method == 'PUT') ? 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' : ''; 
    $to_sign = ($method . "\n" .
            /* Content-MD5 */ "\n" . 
            $content_type . "\n" . 
            $expires . "\n" . s
            '/bucket/' . $id); 
    $signature = '';

    $signer = new Google_Signer_P12(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/'."key.p12"), "notasecret");
    $signature = $signer->sign($to_sign);
    $signature = Google_Utils::urlSafeB64Encode($signature);

    return ('https://bucket.storage.googleapis.com/' . $id . 
            '?GoogleAccessId=' . 'MyServiceAccount@developer.gserviceaccount.com' . 
            '&Expires=' . $expires . '&Signature=' . $signature); 
}
echo storageURL("object_file.docx");
?>`
```

When I copy this url into browser's addressbar it shows me SignatureDoesNotMatch error, I get this XML as output

```
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>
        The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.
    </Message>
    <StringToSign>
        GET 1409582445 /bucket/object_file.docx
    </StringToSign>
</Error>
```

I am not able to understand what is wrong with my code...

P.S. I am able to download the file when i paste this in browser addressbar "https://bucket.storage.googleapis.com/object_file.docx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file I was trying to access has spaces in its name due to some bugs with urlencoding I wasn't able to create proper url for it ...

So for files without spaces works fine with me

Reference -> [Using google cloud storage and gsutil not able to generate valid signedurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562798/using-google-cloud-storage-and-gsutil-not-able-to-generate-valid-signedurl?s=01a186e1-58f9-4eaf-be1b-0b81edbb7b30#comment40120111_25562798)

Answer (score 2):

Check out this section:

```
<StringToSign>
    GET 1409582445 /bucket/object_file.docx
</StringToSign>
```

This is the String that GCS decided you would have signed, based on the incoming request. The newlines are getting stripped somewhere along the way, but there are three things there: the word GET, a timestamp, and the path to the object.

Your code has one thing that this string doesn't have: a Content_Type. The user is downloading an object, so they aren't supplying a content type. Leave that line blank.

Comment: I am leaving $content_type blank, in code it is written if it is not put then set it empty...

I am not able to understand what is wrong with this code, I am newbie to GCS, Would you please pinpoint me at proper place ...

Comment: The String I am signing is GET\n\n\n1409582445\n/bucket/object_file.docx

Comment: Assuming the service account owns or otherwise has permission to access the file, yes. If your problem was permission denied, though, that'd be a different error.

Comment: As mentioned in this link if I try generating signurl with gsutil then it shows me error that service account doesn't have permission, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562798/using-google-cloud-storage-and-gsutil-not-able-to-generate-valid-signedurl .....

See my execution on this link with signurl
http://oi60.tinypic.com/2uhlqgp.jpg

Comment: Is there a specific way to use this generated signurl? or pasting this directly in addressbar will work ?

Comment: Nope, you should be able to paste a signed URL directly into an address bar.

Comment: Then what could be wrong with my code ?
Should I provide specific content-type ?

Comment: Is creation of token is necessary before we ask for signing url?
Token as mentioned in this link -> https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_oauth2_service

Comment: Hey, I came to know that this problem is occurring because of the space in file name, The issue is mentioned in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506562/file-names-with-spaces-returning-signature-mismatch-error-for-signed-urls-in-goo

but I am not able to solve the issue as per the comment in the question

I tried this two things 
$signature = urlencode( base64_encode( $signature ) ); and 
 $signature = Google_Utils::urlSafeB64Encode($signature);

but it gives me signature doesn't match

Comment: Ah, your filename has a space in it? Yes, you need to replace that with a %20. Try using the PHP rawurlencode() function.

Comment: But which string specifically I should encode?
1) Singnature
2) File Name
3) Both
4) None
5) Or something else ?

I have (1) to (4) and didn't succeed ...