# Google Client returns JWT ErrorException : supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key

Tags: php, service-accounts, google-client, google-my-business-api, server-to-server

I'm trying to setup a Google Client, I want to use it with a Google MyBusiness Service as an argument.

I tried every solutions that I've read in Google Client documentation, and also asked for help everywhere.
I still have this ErrorException from JWT that says: "openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key"

```
$config_service_account = [
    "type" => "service_account",
    "project_id" => "MyProjectId",
    "private_key_id" => "831ff22c31476f3af45df4c249adae3feea923f3",
    "private_key" => "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----",
    "client_email" => "AccountServiceEmail",
    "client_id" => "ClientId",
    "auth_uri" => Google_Client::OAUTH2_AUTH_URL,
    "token_uri" => Google_Client::OAUTH2_TOKEN_URI,
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url" => Google_Client::API_BASE_PATH . "/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url" => Google_Client::API_BASE_PATH . "/robot/v1/metadata/x509/AccountServiceUrlCompletion"
];

// Initialisation et instanciation du client, conformément au guide Google
$this->client = new Google_Client();
$this->client->setSubject('MySubject');
$this->client->setApplicationName('MyApplicationName');
$this->client->addScope([
    Google_Service_MyBusiness::PLUS_BUSINESS_MANAGE,
    Google_Service_MyBusiness::BUSINESS_MANAGE
]);

// On fournit à l'instance du client, la configuration (OAuth2 ou Compte de service).
try {
    $this->client->setAuthConfig($config_service_account);
} catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
}
```

I really need your help to find out what's wrong with this code. I'm trying to get Google Reviews.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key with Google APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149200/supplied-key-param-cannot-be-coerced-into-a-private-key-with-google-apis)